# "unclear what you're asking", really?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

[squatting barefoot, bad reputation for gym!](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24193/squatting-barefoot-bad-reputation-for-gym)

One of his questions in the last sentence, and clearly the intent of the overall post:

> Is it really bad to squat in barefoot?

And the close votes were that it was unclear what you're asking? So speaking really clearly, how can you possibly say that you don't clearly know what his question was? Now if you think it's a worthless question with no merit or what have then that's different, but *unclear*?

Comment: The reason comes up as a majority vote. Personally, I think it's just so much more about the particular gym's (or possibly a particular gym member's) policy than about fitness.